# React Native how to clear array of Textinput value

Tags: react-native

//Here is my code

```
let otpTextInput = []; 
   
 const focusNext = (index, value) => {
    if (index < otpTextInput.length - 1 && value) {
      otpTextInput[index + 1].focus();
    }
    if (index === otpTextInput.length - 1) {
      otpTextInput[index].blur();
    }
    const text = otp;
    otp[index] = value;
    
    setOtp(otp);
    if(index == 5){
      checkOtp(otp,state.transactionId);
    }
  };

  const focusPrevious = (key, index) => {
    if (key === 'Backspace' && index !== 0) otpTextInput[index - 1].focus();
  };
    {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((item, index) => (
              <TextInput
                ref={textInputRef => (otpTextInput[index] = textInputRef)}
                key={index}
                autoFocus={index === 0}  
                onFocus={(e) => e.target.select}
                style={styles.TextInputStyleClass}
                placeholder="*"
                maxLength={1}
                numberOfLines={1}
                keyboardType="numeric"
                keyboardBehavior="extend"
                placeholderTextColor={Colors.yellowAmber}
                onChangeText={v => focusNext(index, v)}
                onKeyPress={e => focusPrevious(e.nativeEvent.key, index)}
              />
            ))}
```

I have an array to create textinput multiple times for entering the otp values. Everything works fine in the textinput. But i am not able to clear textinput value. If user clicks submit button i want to clear all the textinput values.

Comment: can you please share the code of SubmitButton clicked event code.

Comment: let enteredOtp = otp[0] + otp[1] + otp[2] + otp[3] + otp[4]+otp[5];
        // let enteredOtp = otp;
        if (enteredOtp.length != 6) {
          Toast.show('Enter Valid OTP');
        } else {
          console.log('enteredotp', enteredOtp);
          validateOtp(enteredOtp);
        }

Comment: once all the otp is entered i am passing that value in validateOtp function which is api call.after getting succesful response i wan to clear the value

Comment: @JatinBhuva otpTextInput is an array

Comment: @JatinBhuva sorry i am not able to see your answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `onSubmitEditing` prop and clearing the `TextInput` there?

For example,

```
<TextInput
  ...
  onSubmitEditing = {(e) => e.target.clear()}
/>
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onsubmitediting

Comment: it saying clear is undefined function

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Another method to consider is the creating an OTP state variable and setting it to an empty array upon clicking the submit button. `[code, setCode] = useState([1,2,3,4,5])` and then `setCode([])` when the submit button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set value to your TextInput and change value of it will do

like this :

```
       <TextInput
                ref={textInputRef => (otpTextInput[index] = textInputRef)}
                key={index}
                autoFocus={index === 0} 
                value={otp[index]}
         ...
```

and in submit button call this kind of helper :

```
const clearInputs = ()=>{
  setOtp(preOtp =>  preOtp.map(() => ''))

}
```

and do not set otp state in this way in focusNext function

> otp[index] = value;

simply use prev like this :

```
setOtp(prevOtp => {
  let temp = prevOtp
  temp[index] = value
  return temp
});
```

Comment: its clearing the value but i am facing issue after clearing.Let's say value is cleared when i click the button but if i try to enter the otp again in textinput the entering value is not visible after clearing.once all the 6 textinput values entered then only the value is getting visible

Comment: aha did you clear this line code ? otp[index] = value;

Comment: yes i have cleared but still facing the issue